# Number of Threads Calculating a single Value

Tags: cuda

I am using CUDA with Compute capability 1.2. I am running my CUDA Code with each element of a matrix calculated by the addtion of other 2 matrices. I am calculating the value of one element by one Thread. I want to know is it possible to use 2 threads for calculating single value.If it is possible, Can anyone plz tell me how to use 2 different threads of same block to calculate the single value?

Comment: If my understanding is right your computation looks like `C[i,j] = A[i,j] + B[i,j]`, is that right? If this is the case I don't see any possible benefit when using two threads to compute `C[i,j]`. Please post some code that shows your kernel and the part where you want to use two threads instead of one single thread.

Comment: @hubs, Thank u for ur reply.. But instead of having Addition operation if I need to use some algorithms like Dynamic Programming, E.g: Matrix chain product.Here, I want to calculate one value of the matrix with 2 threads.Is this possible???

Comment: I'm sure that there this a way to use two threads. But it's not possible to say if it will be a benefit or not. Without any code or exact math equations provided by you it's not possible to answer!

Comment: @hubs, ok.. I will post my code here

Comment: @user3155942: if you have a *real* example or algorithm you want to ask about, please edit your question to clearly describe it. Otherwise I don't understand how anyone could actually answer this question.

Comment: @user3155942: That kernel code looks very broken. Are you saying what you posted is what you can compile, run and get a correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to calculate

```
q = m2[i][k] + m2[(k+1)][j] + p1[(i-1)]*p1[k]*p1[j];
```

by two cores, use a wider variable + less iterations. int2:

```
__shared__ int2 m2[N][N],p1[N],q;
```

could use two cores but not two threads. If you insist on two threads,

```
qThread1 = m2[i][k] + m2[(k+1)][j] //in a kernel
 ...
  ...
 ...
qThread2 = p1[(i-1)]*p1[k]*p1[j] //in another kernel
```

Then you simply add them into q by another thread. Synchronizations, kernel starting overheads, cache utilization can decrease performance as well as decreased instruction level parallelizm. Maybe kernel occupation increases but not sure if it tolerates the above negatives.